Outlook version 2403 doesn't show an addin when using requirement set 1.13
We have implemented a web addin using Outlook.js that shows in the task pane when an email is read. Now we need to use this addin also when multiple email are selected, so following the Microsoft Documentation we need to use the 1.13 requirement set.
Unfortunately the addin is not shown by Outlook on the Ribbon when in the unified manifest we change the "requirements.capabilities.minVersion" property to "1.13", if we set the "requirements.capabilities.minVersion" property to 1.12, leaving all the rest of the manifest the same, the addin is shown again.
It seems to be an incompatibility of the Outlook client, but it shouldn't, we are using the Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2403 Build 16.0.17425.20236) 64 bit updated with the Monthly Enterprise Channel and from here as per my understanding the 1.13 should be supported. Am I interpreting the version support table wrong? Or we are doing something wrong on the manifest?
Our manifest is the following:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/teams/v1.17/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.17",
  "id": "${{CLIENT_ID}}",
  "version": "${{MANIFEST_VERSION}}",
  "name": {
    "short": "*** add-in",
    "full": "*** add-in"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "*** add-in",
    "full": "****"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "assets/outline.png",
    "color": "assets/color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#230201",
  "developer": {
    "name": "***",
    "websiteUrl": "***",
    "privacyUrl": "***",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "***"
  },
  "localizationInfo": {
    "defaultLanguageTag": "en-us",
    "additionalLanguages": []
  },
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "${{CLIENT_ID}}",
    "resource": "api://${{TAB_DOMAIN}}/${{CLIENT_ID}}"
  },
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": {
      "resourceSpecific": [
        {
          "name": "Mailbox.ReadWrite.User",
          "type": "Delegated"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "validDomains": ["${{TAB_DOMAIN}}", "${{TAB_DOMAIN}}/auth", "https://login.microsoftonline.com"],
  "extensions": [
    {
      "requirements": {
        "scopes": ["mail"]
      },
      "runtimes": [
        {
          "requirements": {
            "capabilities": [
              {
                "name": "Mailbox",
                "minVersion": "1.13"
              }
            ]
          },
          "id": "TaskPaneRuntime",
          "type": "general",
          "code": {
            "page": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/taskpane.html"
          },
          "lifetime": "short",
          "actions": [
            {
              "id": "TaskPaneRuntimeShow",
              "type": "openPage",
              "view": "dashboard",
              "pinnable": true,
              "supportsNoItemContext": true,
              "multiselect": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "ribbons": [
        {
          "contexts": ["mailRead"],
          "tabs": [
            {
              "builtInTabId": "TabDefault",
              "groups": [
                {
                  "id": "msgReadGroup",
                  "label": "***",
                  "icons": [
                    {
                      "size": 16,
                      "url": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/assets/icon-16.png"
                    },
                    {
                      "size": 32,
                      "url": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/assets/icon-32.png"
                    },
                    {
                      "size": 80,
                      "url": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/assets/icon-80.png"
                    }
                  ],
                  "controls": [
                    {
                      "id": "msgReadOpenPaneButton",
                      "type": "button",
                      "label": "*** add-in",
                      "icons": [
                        {
                          "size": 16,
                          "url": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/assets/_logo_PNG.png"
                        },
                        {
                          "size": 32,
                          "url": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/assets/_logo_PNG.png"
                        },
                        {
                          "size": 80,
                          "url": "${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/assets/_logo_PNG.png"
                        }
                      ],
                      "supertip": {
                        "title": "*** add-in",
                        "description": "Opens a pane displaying all available document operations."
                      },
                      "actionId": "TaskPaneRuntimeShow"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

We tried different changes in the manifest, but the evidence is that the problem raises onky when the requirement changes.
Has somebody had the same problem?

Issue has been resolved by Microsoft, yesterday here
